# Unknown bit in the output of encryption of data using SIMECK32 cipher?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, differential-analysis, lightweight

How is the **unknown bits** (**annotated by red arrow in figure below**) come in the **OUTPUT** after round 1 and round 2 ?

Following is the **pictorial representation of SIMECK round function** operation.

[image: simeck round function forward encryption]

Ref: [Research Paper (figure 3)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019019300468)

Comment: it is SIMECK32.